# ASP gridview performance when in Ajax accordian

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a reasonably simple page setup with four accordian panes and four gridviews in each accordian.

The gridviews in themselves are bound to 4 entity data sources with paging and sorting enabled on each and I have a command field which shows the edit/deleted button on each

I am seeing a massive performance issue when selecting edit/ Update/cancel from the gridview row in as much as it takes 20 + seconds to enter the edit state and then another 20 if you cancel out of edit mode.

I have pulled out the contents of one of the accordian panes into a seperate page and it enters edit mode in about 1-2 seconds

Does anyone know if the accordian has performance impact and whether the other gridviews would cause an issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anyway around this and resorted to swapping out the asp panels holding all the content in the accoridan panels and moving them into iframes which has massively improved performance